# .Net Core OAuth Nested Claims are not mapped back to user

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, .net-core, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to gain access to the claims after OAuth:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = COINBASE_AUTH_ID;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOAuth(COINBASE_AUTH_ID, options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration["Coinbase:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Coinbase:ClientSecret"];
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-coinbase");

    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize";
    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/token";
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/user";

    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:coinbase:avatar", "avatar_url");

    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
            request.Headers.Add("CB-VERSION", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()); 
            var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            context.RunClaimActions(user);
        }
    };
});
```

To my understanding after obtaining the access token in the OnCreatingTicket I obtain a user through the UserEndpoint.   When I call                 `context.RunClaimActions(user)` this should map the claims I've set in my options to my user.

In My Index model I try to obtain the mapped Claims like so:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string CoinbaseId { get; set; }

    public string CoinbaseAvatar { get; set; }

    public string CoinbaseName { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            CoinbaseName = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
            CoinbaseId = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
            CoinbaseAvatar = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:coinbase:avatar")?.Value;

        }
    }
```

Yet the model returns all null values.  My response from coinbase contains all 3 of those claims, yet they don't seem to be mapped to my in memory user, does anyone know why?

**EDIT**

It turns out Coinbase doesn't return the user object directly it returns the user object wrapped in an object named Data.

I've tried prefixing my map with

```
options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "data.id");
```

I think I'll need to parse the data object manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this I just grabbed the nested property in the JObject with `SelectToken`

```
var userData = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
var user = userData["data"];

context.RunClaimActions(JObject.FromObject(user));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ClaimActions.MapJsonSubKey` to navigate to a nested key.